# Is the X-ray image leading into Fringe commercial breaks have any meaning?

Tags: fringe

I was intrigued by the images that lead commercial in Fringe. Goggling for "*fringe images*" showed my that they are [glyphs](http://www.fringepedia.net/wiki/Fringe_Symbols) and they are part of a code.

[image: Decoded Glyphs]

So, each Glyphs is a letter that form a word per episode, but beyond that, is there any meaning for those [decoded words](http://fringepedia.net/wiki/Glyphs_code)? They just look random to me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The decoded glyph words usually are a one-word comment/hint/theme for that episode.  It [took](http://arstechnica.com/media/news/2009/04/secret-codes-in-tv-series-fringe.ars/2) [months](http://www.juliansanchez.com/2009/04/07/solution-to-the-fringe-glyph-cipher/) for viewers to crack the code, so initially it was a nice extra thrown in by the showrunners to keep viewers engaged in a mystery.

Comment: Sanchez does say "I should note the possibility that solving the substitution cipher is only step one", so it's possible that there is yet more to be found.

Comment: @TonyMeyer That was 2 years ago, and AFAIK there isn't anything further.